# Cannot connect to shibd process, a site adminstrator should be notified

Tags: apache, centos7, shibboleth

I have been trying to configure shibboleth on centos. But Shibboleth does not support SElinux enable mode.

Because of that i was getting the below

> shib_handler: error while processing request: Cannot connect to shibd
>   process, a site adminstrator should be notified.

Solution - Check centos SELinux mode using "getenforce command " by default its enforcing. Run "setenforce 0" that is disable SElinux mode and should change mode to "Permissive"